Differentiability of $f(x)=\sum_{r_n \leq x} \frac{1}{2^n}$
Let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.  We define $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\sum_{r_n \leq x} \frac{1}{2^n}$.
The question asks to study the left and right-differentiability of $f$ at any $x \in [0,1]$.
What I did: It is quite easy to prove that $f$ is

well-defined and increasing,
continuous at every irrational, and
right-continuous at every rational, but not left-continuous.

However, the question of the differentiability confuses me. I know that being monotonic, $f$ should be differentiable a.e. But the points at which $f$ is differentiable seem to depend strongly of the enumeration $(r_n)$. Indeed, for every $a \in [0,1)$, I think I can construct an enumeration $(r_n)$ that makes the function $f$ non-differentiable at $a$.
Here is the idea: let $a \in [0,1)$. There exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a+\frac{1}{5^N} < 1$. Then for every $n\geq N$, let $x_n$ be a rational number such that $a + \frac{1}{5^{n+1}} < x_n < a+\frac{1}{5^n}$. Now I choose an enumeration $(r_n)$ of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ such that for every $n \geq N$, $r_{2n} = x_n$ (this is possible since the $x_n$, for $n\geq N$, are distinct by construction). Then for every $n\geq N$, the function $f$ associated to this enumeration satisfies
$f(a + \frac{1}{5^n}) - f(a) \geq \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$. So $f$ is not (right-)differentiable at $a$.
My question: is there any way to describe completely the points at which $f$ is left-differentiable and right-differentiable, in the terms of the enumeration $(r_n)$?

Relevant is Points of differentiability of $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n : q_n < x} c_n$ (mathoverflow).

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1921071/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2672366/42969

@Mittens Thanks for the feedback. However, the linked question is not exactly the same (I am interested only in the case $c_n=1/2^n$... even though to be fair, I would expect the general situation to be quite similar), and more importantly, the answer to that question, interesting though it may be, does not really answer it.

@Toctocguy: the solution is the same. Your function is the cumulative function of a probability measure supported on the rational numbers and that gives mass $2^{-n}$ to the $n$-th rational number $r_n$ (of course all this depends on the particular listing of $\mathbb{Q}$). This is a singular measure w.r.t the Lebesgue measure and so, by Leguesghe's theorem the symmetric derivative (derivative) is the same Lebesgue a.s. as the Radon Nykodym derivative which is $0$. Of course, your function is discontinuous at every rational and continuous at every irrational.

@Mittens Maybe I dont understand the answer very well, but I dont see where it answers my question, which is to describe the set of points where $f$ is differentiable ; if I undestand it correctly, it only proves that $f'=0$ a.e., which is not what I am asking for. Am I misunderstanding something ?

@Toctocguy: Your function is also locally integrable and continuous  at every irrational number. I thinks you can see what the Lebesgue points should be. In general, it is hard to describe what the Lebesgue points of a locally inexorable functions are, except that almost every point is such a point. Some knowledge of measure theory would be helpful here ...
